# NSResponder methods only calling setNeedsDisplay

Tags: cocoa, nsview, setneedsdisplay, nsresponder

I have a subclass of an openGl view. In one of the methods, I set a flag to draw the background black or white. At the end of the method i call setNeedsDisplay. This never gets called! I have a setNeedsDisplay also in the mouseDownEvent. When I click on the view IT CALLS IT! and my background changes color. Any ideas? Here is the code.

in the openGL view

```
-(long)setBackgroundBlack:(BOOL)flag{
if(flag == YES){
    blkBg = YES;

    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}else if (flag == NO){
    blkBg = NO;
    [self  setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}

if (flag == blkBg){

    return 0;



}else{
    return 1;
}
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
lastDragLocation = [[self superview] convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
    NSPoint newPoint;
    newPoint.x = lastDragLocation.x * (2.0 / self.bounds.size.width) - 1.0;
    newPoint.y = lastDragLocation.y * (2.0 / self.bounds.size.width) - 1.0;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

in app delegate

```
-(IBAction)claim1931BW:(id)sender{

long res = [_myPlotView setBackgroundBlack:NO];

NSLog(@"%ld", res);
[self.cie1931BWMenu setState:NSOnState];
[self.cie1931ColorMenu setState:NSOffState];

}
```

Comment: Where do you actually change the background colour? This ultimately needs to be done in `drawRect`.

Comment: @boyfarrell Inside drawRect I call [self drawColorCIE] and inside that method I have the openGl drawing code that has the flag for the background changing. drawRect is not being called from the -setBackgroundBlack method.

Comment: It's hard to follow the logic of your methods and variables because of structure and naming. I'd strip all of this out start again. Give your view a property `backgroundColour`, and in `drawRect` use `NSRectFill` to fill this colour. All you have to do now is make your methods change the view's background colour and call `setNeedsDisplay`.

Comment: @boyfarrell so I figured out that I have to subclass the OpenGL custom view and make all my -setNeedsDisplay on the subclass. Thanks though. All the method names make sense for the program.